# PowerShell Issue with a bulk delete script

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to delete everything with less than 2kB file size and am using the following code:

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *.html -Recurse -File |
    ? {$_.Length -lt 2000} |
    % {Remove-Item $_.FullName}
```

I keep getting errors like this:

```
Remove-Item : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet.
The specified wildcard character pattern is not valid: 07 somefilename
filename.mp3
At line:1 char:66
+ ... -Recurse -File | ? {$_.Length -lt 2000} | % {Remove-Item $_.FullName}
+                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Comment: Does the path or fullname have square brackets [ ] in it?  Those are wildcards.

Comment: Try `Remove-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably avoid the [ ] wildcard in filename problem, piping the fileinfo object directly to remove-item.

```
ls $path *.html -r -file | where length -lt 2000 | remove-item -whatif
```